# UDP packets seen in Wireshark, but not being received in C# application (WPF)

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I have a WPF application that opens a listening UDP socket on a specific port.  This application can receive udp packets when it comes from an application on the same machine sending to the machine's IP and the specific port.  However, when I try to get the same UDP packets from a different IP address (being sent to the same IP/Port), I can see them arriving on Wireshark, but the application does not receive any data.  I'm working in a secure environment and do not have permissions to change any firewall rules.  But is this a firewall problem?

Comment: The port may be used by another application.  From cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give the ports being used by TCP and UDP.

Comment: Yes, I checked this. The ports are not being used by any other process.

Comment: Is wireshark installed on same machine that code is running?  The only reasons I can think is 1) port being blocked by virus checker or firewall 2) The TTL is zero and not being forwarded.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live

Comment: Yes, wireshark is installed on the same machine where the code is running. [There really is no TTL concept for UDP packets.](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77650/how-traceroute-add-ttl-field-to-udp-header#:~:text=There%20is%20really%20no%20TTL%20concept%20for%20UDP.&text=The%20TTL%20field%20is%20within,each%20router%20the%20packet%20passes.)  I suspect it's my firewall, thank you for answering.

Comment: TTL is in the IP header and applies to both UDP and TCP.  TTL may not apply to broadcast UDP, but will apply to non broadcast UDP : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#Header